# How to handle below pattern matching in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, special-characters

How to do the below mentioned pattern match?

Below input is in an array:

```
@array=("gs : asti:34:234", "gs : asti:344:543:wet");
```

I used `foreach loop` so that I split them and I'm pushing them into an array.

Help me in resolving the below issue.

```
foreach(@array)
{
    if($_ =~ /gs/ig)
    {

        my @arr2 = split(":",$_); #Splitting the matched pattern
        push(@y,$arr2[1]);
    }
}
```

Acutal output is: `asti , asti`
Desired/Expected Output : `asti:34:234 , asti:344:543:wet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way, [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) strings in only two parts:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array=('gs : asti:34:234', 'gs : asti:344:543:wet');

foreach(@array)
{
    if($_ =~ m/gs/ig)
    {
        my @arr2 = split(":", $_, 2);
        $arr2[1] =~ s/^\s+//;   #to remove the white-space
        push(my @y,$arr2[1]);
        print "@y\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
asti:34:234
asti:344:543:wet
```

Comment: What if my input is like below and how to handle it? @array=('gs : asti:34:234', 'gs : asti:344:543:wet-45','gs : asti:344:543:wet%43');

Comment: @Sam333 : For this input output will be `asti:34:234`
`asti:344:543:wet-45`
`asti:344:543:wet%43` What is you expecting?

Comment: Input: gs : asti:34:234, gs : asti:344:543:wet-45, gs :  asti:344:543:wet%43   Output : asti:34:234,asti:344:543:wet-45,asti:344:543:wet%43

Comment: @Sam333 : Code will work for this input also. You can change your array with new value. It will give you desire output. Don't forget to quoted value with single or double quote.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex capture instead of split can simplify the code, you're already using a regex anyway so why not save a step:

```
my @array = ("gs : asti:34:234", "gs : asti:344:543:wet");
my @y     = ();
foreach my $e (@array) {
    push @y, $1 if $e =~ m/^gs : (.*)$/i;
}
```